# XUL event: new page loads / get content of a page

Tags: firefox, xul

How can I catch the event when "a page starts to load in the Browser"?

How can I access the HTML and manipulate it with XUL?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question as this. I found documentation, but had trouble getting the code to run in Firefox 3.6.12. I made some changes and managed to get it working:

```
this._loadHandler = function(event) {

var myDomain = 'www.yahoo.com';

let doc = event.originalTarget;
//alert(doc.defaultView.location.href);
if (doc instanceof HTMLDocument) {

    var re = new RegExp(myDomain);
    if (doc.defaultView.location.href.match(re)) {
        alert("Successful match");
    }

}};


gBrowser.addEventListener("load", this._loadHandler, true);
```

This was modified from the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

HTH

Comment: I got a simple FF plugin created pretty quickly and then, jeez, it was obnoxiously non-obvious how to get the page load event to get caught. I wish I knew why this stuff seems so non-intuitive.

Comment: Anyway, if interested, see: https://github.com/rkiddy/classy-locator-firefox-extension.git

Answer (score 1):

There is a large amount of [documentation and sample code for this very task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) already on Mozilla's site.  You question is a big vague though, so I may be linking you to the wrong page.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially taken from the mozilla site

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);

var myExtension = {

    init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");  
    if(appcontent)
        appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);  
    },

    onPageLoad: function(event) {
        var doc = event.originalTarget;
        var myDiv = doc.getElementById("myDiv");
        //do something interesting with it
    }
}
```

have fun